# How to reduce the number of user profiles reported

Tags: user-profile-service, synchronisation

My user profile service was reporting 1,000 or so users before i reprovisioned but after i did that i did a sync with out my exclusion filters set on teh connection to my AD and it imported in an extra 2000 or so. Is there any way to reset it so that i can re run the import with the correct exclusions so that it generates the right number?

Comment: this link might help http://paulliebrand.com/2011/05/26/user-profile-synchronization-database-growing-out-of-control/

Answer (score 1):

I found what i was looking for....what you have to do is enable the MySite cleanup timer job and it will purge the profiles marked for removal. I had it disabled while i was testing and didn't turn it back on. On